# can not believe this: chef lazy block get executed 3 times

Tags: chef-infra, lazy-evaluation

I can not believe this! I ran into a chef issue: `file` content `lazy` ruby block gets executed 3 times, but it is supposed to be only run once.

```
$ sudo cat /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/infra-tmp/recipes/default.rb
aaa = 'aaaaaa'
puts "=========before"
file '/tmp/a.pem' do
  puts "==== inner begin"
  content lazy { xxx(aaa) }
end
puts "=========end"
```

the xxx is a common function defined in infra-common libraries,

```
def xxx(aaa=nil)
        puts "========xxx: #{aaa}"
        puts caller
        aaa
end
```

guess how many times the xxx get executed?  3!

```
$ sudo chef-client -o infra-tmp --skip-cookbook-sync
Starting Chef Client, version 13.12.3
...
Compiling Cookbooks...
=========before
==== inner begin
=========end
Converging 1 resources
Recipe: infra-tmp::default
  * file[/tmp/a.pem] action create========xxx: aaaaaa
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/infra-tmp/recipes/default.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in from_file'
...
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.12.3/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:191:in `managing_content?'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.12.3/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:94:in `load_current_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.12.3/lib/chef/provider.rb:154:in `run_action'
...
========xxx: aaaaaa
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/infra-tmp/recipes/default.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in from_file'
...
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.12.3/lib/chef/provider/file/content.rb:27:in `file_for_provider'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.12.3/lib/chef/file_content_management/content_base.rb:40:in `tempfile'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.12.3/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:450:in `tempfile'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.12.3/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:327:in `do_generate_content'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.12.3/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:140:in `action_create'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.12.3/lib/chef/provider.rb:171:in `run_action'
...
========xxx: aaaaaa
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/infra-tmp/recipes/default.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in from_file'
...
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.12.3/lib/chef/provider/file/content.rb:29:in `file_for_provider'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.12.3/lib/chef/file_content_management/content_base.rb:40:in `tempfile'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.12.3/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:450:in `tempfile'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.12.3/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:327:in `do_generate_content'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.12.3/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:140:in `action_create'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.12.3/lib/chef/provider.rb:171:in `run_action'
...
```

I've checked the chef source code,

```
$ cat -n /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.12.3/lib/chef/provider/file/content.rb | grep -vE '^\s*(#|$)'
    18
    19  require "chef/file_content_management/content_base"
    20  require "chef/file_content_management/tempfile"
    21
    22  class Chef
    23    class Provider
    24      class File
    25        class Content < Chef::FileContentManagement::ContentBase
    26          def file_for_provider
    27            if @new_resource.content
    28              tempfile = Chef::FileContentManagement::Tempfile.new(@new_resource).tempfile
    29              tempfile.write(@new_resource.content)
    30              tempfile.close
    31              tempfile
    32            else
    33              nil
    34            end
    35          end
    36        end
    37      end
    38    end
    39  end
```

Turns out it is because `@new_resource.content` being referenced 3 times,
without using a local var to cache it.

Is this a bug of Chef?
Not sure whether other chef resource has same bug.

EDIT: I ended up with @var instance var to cache, instead of node.run_state which cause multi custom resources only use first cached value.

```
file ... do
  ...
  content lazy {
          @any_name || (@any_name  = some_function(some_param))
  }
  ...
end
```

Comment: What's the reason for using `lazy` evaluation for file `content`?

Comment: lazy means do not evaluate it in compiling phase, instead, in execution phase.  Chef run recipes in two phase, first in compilation phase, it call `file`'s `do end` block, evaluate all things in it except the lazy block, as a result, it register the instance of `file` into a queue, not change file yet. And so on for all such things such as `execute` ..., , all things get queued, then in second phase: execution phase, it actually change the file or execute command etc, in the order of queue.  Without the `lazy`, the `xxx` function will be called too early, some related things are not ready.

Comment: I was looking for the reason why you are using value in execution phase, rather than a value generated in compile phase, and not the explanation of the differences between the two phases.

Comment: Without the lazy, the xxx function will be called too early, some related things are not ready

Comment: believe me, there are cases that you have to use `lazy`, see https://docs.chef.io/resource_common/#lazy-evaluation. Besides, running things in compiling phase often frustrates users when error happens, the error message will be not that easy to understand which `resource` did wrong.

Comment: So does the `file` resource depend on another resource which will run prior to this in execution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227791/discussion-between-seshadri-c-and-osexp2003).

Comment: let us forget the reason why use `lazy`, that is not the point. I know different resource can  notify or subscribe changes.

Comment: if no one realize that this is a bug of chef, then I am going to close this question.

Comment: If you are of a firm belief of this being a bug, please create an issue in upstream code. You can add it as answer so that it will be helpful to SO community.

Comment: @osexp2003 I don't know if it's a bug, the question is: what do you get in the file at the end ? But as your method print the caller, it will obviously print twice, once at compile time, a second time when lazy eval it (you have two level of caller here due to how chef compile recipes before converge (check your first lines of log, ====end appears before the content is processed, your put inside the file resource is still evaluated at compile time.

Comment: > what do you get in the file at the end?   The result of calling xxx which in turn calls remote API (such as a REST API), I don't want the the remote API being called 3 times, no one like that, no matter that is a bug or not.